# transferring a time series from excell to R.studio

Tags: rstudio

Hello this is probably very basic although I can not find a similar question and have tried many similar fixes found here.
Anyway im trying to transfer a hourly time series from xcell as .csv to R and create a bar plot that accurately uses the hourly data I have. so far r is thinking that what I have is consecutive numbers and ignores time

```
heres my data:
time1   chrono1
22:00   0
22:30   0
23:00   0
23:30   0
0:00    1.1
0:30    2.6
1:00    4.8
1:30    7
2:00    10.8
2:30    14
3:00    15.1
3:30    12.58
4:00    10
4:30    7
5:00    4.9
5:30    3.8
6:00    2.6
6:30    2.2
7:00    1.25
7:30    1.18
8:00    1
8:30    0.8
9:00    0.8
9:30    0.3
10:00   0
10:30   0
```

heres the base code im using:

```
ggplot(hourly, aes(x=time1,y=chrono1)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') 
BPlot
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a couple of issues. First if you want a bar for each time convert your time to a factor using as.factor(). Then instead of geom_barplot use geom_col(). That should get you mostly there and then you can change the aesthetics of the plot as you see fit